# Display Login Controller when logout from facebook

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am developping an iOS application requiring to be logged in with Facebook. So I have a Login View Controller which is my first window and a bunch of controllers only accessible for the logged user.

In my LoginViewController, I have implemented facebook delegate:

```
// LoginViewController.swift extract

// Facebook Delegate Methods
func loginViewShowingLoggedInUser(loginView : FBLoginView!) {
    println("User Logged In")
    //Push main controller of the app
}

...

func loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser(loginView : FBLoginView!) {
    println("User Logged Out")
    //PROBABLY MISSING CODE HERE to display LoginViewController (self)
}

func loginView(loginView : FBLoginView!, handleError:NSError) {
    println("Error: \(handleError.localizedDescription)")
}
```

What I would like to do is: displaying the LoginViewController everytime the facebook delegate calls the log out method, no matter which controller is currently displayed. I can't simply push the view because the logout method is called everytime the view is displayed, so i end up in a infinite loop. Could you explain to me what is the cleanest way to do that ? Should I let the delegate method in the LoginViewController ?

Bonus question: The facebook delegate is on login view controller, the logout method is still called, even if another controller is displayed. Since `loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser` is a instance method, am I sure the instance of my controller will never be destroyed and my delegate method always be called even if LoginViewController is not visible ?

Answer (score 0):

You could put your first NavigationController as your rootController. At launch time you put up a modal LoginViewController if the user is not logged in. And if the user is logs out while the app is running you simply put up another modal LoginViewController.

Comment: I will probably have different Navigation Controllers. I don't want to manage which Controller should be displayed when login/logout in each of them. That's why I would like to use the facebook delegate to display the login or main controller.